# Ubuntu has no terminal

Tags: command-line

I originally tried to install 64-bit ubuntu in VirtualBox but it didn't work.
I then tried 32-bit (16.04) and it installed but there is no terminal on the
desktop. Other than that , it looks just like the screen in the Udemy Linux 
course. Obviously it's useless for a Linux course without a terminal.
Any idea why it's missing ?

Comment: All my 16.04 Desktop installs have a terminal. It's been part of the default install since the beginning. What makes you believe that yours does not? It's not on the shortcut bar by default. Have you used the Desktop Search to look for it?

Comment: *it looks just like the screen in the Udemy Linux course.*: What does that mean? Have you tried finding terminal in applications? Default terminal shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+T. Have you tried that also?